# Community version username and password

Tags: baqend

I could not find the default username and password that https://www.baqend.com community edition comes with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should contact them directly to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the default credentials are root root.